# Can't compile pdf using R sweave. Latex error: file 'ae.sty' not found

Tags: r, pdf, latex, sweave

I can't compile a `pdf` using R sweave. I keep getting the following error

> Latex error: file 'ae.sty' not found

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}
Hello, world.
\end{document}
```

Why do I keep getting this error? Do I need to install another package with pdf compilation functions?

I'm using windows, and my tex install is the package `tinytex`.

Comment: It may help people to debug this if you add some details of your system; what was the full error? what operating system are you using? What tex install? Can you render this tex file outside R (omitting the SweaveOpts line) ? Thanks

Comment: I'm using windows, and my tex install is the package tinytex on R.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I do not use tinytex so I'm afraid i can't offer any help. I do note that `ae` package is not listed in the [`tinytex` install](https://github.com/yihui/tinytex/blob/master/tools/pkgs-custom.txt) whereas it is listed as [fundamental](https://packages.debian.org/buster/texlive-latex-base) by texlive. But given how many r users that use tinytex I doubt this is an issue.  ...

Comment: ... From https://yihui.org/tinytex/ there is also `tinytex:::install_yihui_pkgs()` which has the [`ae` package](https://github.com/yihui/tinytex/blob/master/tools/pkgs-yihui.txt) . May be worth adding the code to how you installed `tinytex` and what code you used to execute the sweave file i.e. perhaps `install.packages('tinytex'); tinytex::install_tinytex()` then `tinytex::pdflatex('test.tex')` .

Answer (score 7):

```r
packs <- c("`ae.sty'","`grfext.sty'") 

for (i in 1:length(packs)) {     
    tinytex::parse_install(text = paste('! LaTeX Error: File', packs[i],'not found.'))
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
You can use the vector to add all the packages that you may need and then use the for loop to install all them from the R terminal.

packs <- c("`setspace.sty'", "`float.sty'", "`amssymb.sty'", "`utf8.sty'", "`fancyhdr.sty'", "`tabularx.sty'", "`hyperref.sty'", "`etoolbox.sty'", "`lmodern.sty") 

for (i in 1:length(packs)) {     
     tinytex::parse_install(text = paste('! LaTeX Error: File', packs[i],'not found.'))
}
```